# How Should You Horizontally Center an Element Using CSS?

Tags: css

Every example of using CSS to horizontally center an element that I have seen so far says to set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`. I'm not very experienced in CSS, so I'm wondering if there's a reason to set both those properties rather than just setting one or the other to `50%`? Would there be side-effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the left margin to 50% will cause the left edge of the box to be centered, which is not quite the same as having the entire box centered.

Another approach which is commonly used is to set the `left` property to `50%`, setting a fixed width, and setting the left margin to be negative one half of the fixed width.

Comment: This approach is good if you can fix widths. However, that doesn't always work when you are writing sites that are responsive or designed to work on a variety of different screen sizes. You can often use a display of inline-block, with `text-align: center` set on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You added the `css3` tag to your question. One option in modern Browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is to use Flexbox. Add `display: flex; justify-content: center` to the parent. This will center its children.

CSS Tricks has an excellent guide to Flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/